# Issue inserting into MySQL database in python

Tags: python, mysql

Currently receiving the following error when I try and insert into my database with python. If you all could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

```
        league_Build_Data(1,0,'Infinity Edge, Mobility Boots, Black Clever, Deaths Dance, Essense Reaver, Guardian Angle', 2431, 'Caitlyn, Blitzcrank, Lee Sin, Ahri, Trundle', 'Anivia, Akali, Draven, Nami, Fiddle Sticks', 12, 3, 15, 231)

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'kill, death, assist, creep_score) VALUES (1, 0, 'Infinity Edge, Mobility Boots, ' at line 1
```

Here is the code running:

```
import mysql.connector



def league_Build_Data(win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score):
    sql = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="pass", database="league_Data")
    print("Connected to database")
    cursor = sql.cursor()
    query = ("INSERT INTO league_Build_Data"
        "(win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score)"
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
    value = (win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score)
    cursor.execute(query, value)
    sql.commit();
    print(cursor.rowcount, "Leauge of Legends build data recorded into database!")


#Testing function
win = 1
lose = 0
build = 'Infinity Edge, Mobility Boots, Black Clever, Deaths Dance, Essense Reaver, Guardian Angle'
game_Length = 2431
champions_team = 'Caitlyn, Blitzcrank, Lee Sin, Ahri, Trundle'
champions_enemy = 'Anivia, Akali, Draven, Nami, Fiddle Sticks'
kill = 12
death = 3
assist = 15
creep_score = 231
league_Build_Data(win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: INSET or INSERT?

Comment: My god I feel so stupid now, but even with the changes the code fails to execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `INSET` should be `INSERT`? Also you have 9 `%s` items in the query but 10 values (and 10 columns in the DB it seems).

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'kill, death, assist, creep_score) VALUES (1, 0, 'Infinity Edge, Mobility Boots, ' at line 1

This is the new error I am receiving

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your SQL error, I noticed as I broke it down:

```
query = "INSERT INTO league_Build_Data (win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
```

is quite a long line.
If you change the above line to

```
query = ("INSERT INTO league_Build_Data "
        "(win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score) "
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s); ") #<--- Notice the ;
```

Remove said **;** and change the line to this:

```
query = ("INSERT INTO league_Build_Data"
        "(win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team, champions_enemy, kill, death, assist, creep_score)"
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
```

Then your SQL should work.

I would also recommend instead of assigning `w = win` and so on, just have

```
value = (win, lose, build, game_Length, champions_team....)
```

because you are just adding extra lines.

Comment: I had the variables originally like that but I was trying to see why something else wasn't working and changed it to that. But Ill clean it up

Comment: Ah, I understand. Did removing the semi-colon solve the issue?

Comment: Maybe an issue with this line `league_Build_Data(1 , 0, 'Infinity Edge, Mobility Boots, Black Clever, Deaths Dance, Essense Reaver, Guardian Angle', 2431, 'Caitlyn, Blitzcrank, Lee Sin, Ahri, Trundle', 'Anivia, Akali, Draven, Nami, Fiddle Sticks', 12, 3, 15, 231)`

Comment: @SageHopkins try changing your cursor.execute to this: 
    cursor.execute(query, (w, l, b, g, c, e, k, d, a, cs))

Comment: same error occurred, I think it has something to do with the string in the data I pass when I call the functions 

`league_Build_Data(1 , 0, 'Infinity Edge, Mobility Boots, Black Clever, Deaths Dance, Essense Reaver, Guardian Angle', 2431, 'Caitlyn, Blitzcrank, Lee Sin, Ahri, Trundle', 'Anivia, Akali, Draven, Nami, Fiddle Sticks', 12, 3, 15, 231)`

     `File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 264, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 395, in cmd_query`